# Simple Payment Channel contract is not signing payments and returns false

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js

I have deployed the smart contract of Payment channel and every thing is working fine but at the time of closing the channel signature is not being validate.
I think passing the arguments in a wrong way or maybe payment that i'm signing is not returning the correct signer.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract SimplePaymentChannel {
    address public sender;     // The account sending payments.
    address public recipient;  // The account receiving the payments.
    uint256 public expiration; // Timeout in case the recipient never 
    closes.

    function SimplePaymentChannel(address _recipient, uint256 duration)
        public
        payable
    {
        sender = msg.sender;
        recipient = _recipient;
        expiration = now + duration;
    }

    function isValidSignature(uint256 amount, bytes signature)
        internal
        view
        returns (bool)
    {
        bytes32 message = prefixed(keccak256(this, amount));

        // Check that the signature is from the payment sender.
        return recoverSigner(message, signature) == sender;
    }

    // The recipient can close the channel at any time by presenting a signed
    // amount from the sender. The recipient will be sent that amount, and the
    // remainder will go back to the sender.
    function close(uint256 amount, bytes signature) public {
        require(msg.sender == recipient);
        require(isValidSignature(amount, signature));

        recipient.transfer(amount);
        selfdestruct(sender);
    }

    // The sender can extend the expiration at any time.
    function extend(uint256 newExpiration) public {
        require(msg.sender == sender);
        require(newExpiration > expiration);

        expiration = newExpiration;
    }

    // If the timeout is reached without the recipient closing the channel, then
    // the ether is released back to the sender.
    function claimTimeout() public {
        require(now >= expiration);
        selfdestruct(sender);
    }

    function splitSignature(bytes sig)
        internal
        pure
        returns (uint8, bytes32, bytes32)
    {
        require(sig.length == 65);

        bytes32 r;
        bytes32 s;
        uint8 v;

        assembly {
            // first 32 bytes, after the length prefix
            r := mload(add(sig, 32))
            // second 32 bytes
            s := mload(add(sig, 64))
            // final byte (first byte of the next 32 bytes)
            v := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
        }

        return (v, r, s);
    }

    function recoverSigner(bytes32 message, bytes sig)
        internal
        pure
        returns (address)
    {
        uint8 v;
        bytes32 r;
        bytes32 s;

        (v, r, s) = splitSignature(sig);

        return ecrecover(message, v, r, s);
    }

    // Builds a prefixed hash to mimic the behavior of eth_sign.
    function prefixed(bytes32 hash) internal pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hash);
    }
}
```

And this is my signing js file.

```js
var BN = require('bn.js')
var abi = require('ethereumjs-abi')
const eutil = require('ethereumjs-util');

var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider"); 
var mnemonic = ""; // 12 word mnemonic
const Web3 = require('web3');

var provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(mnemonic, 
    "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/4e962d53cc894df2a63436f519d1e9d0");

const web3 = new Web3(provider);
var s;


function constructPaymentMessage(contractAddress, amount) {
    return abi.soliditySHA3(
        ["address", "uint256"],
        [contractAddress, amount],
    );
}

async function signMessage(message, callback) {
    account = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    web3.eth.sign("0x" + message.toString("hex"), account[0], callback);
}

function signPayment(contractAddress, amount, callback) {
    var message = constructPaymentMessage(contractAddress, amount);
    console.log("message is", message);
    signMessage(message, async (err, signature) => {
        try {
            s = signMessage
            console.log("sig", signature);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("siasdsdg", error.message);
        }
    });
}


signPayment('0x0c991FcDcc1cC9EA6398CbC40A71Bc2bFAe04CbE', 
    '1000000000000000000', function (err, signer) {
});
```

Please let me know where i'm wrong thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to have `s = signature` instead of `s = signMessage`?

Comment: Also, where is the code that calls  `close()` on the smart contract?

Comment: Maybe you can point to a failed transaction on Rinkeby. That would make it easier to debug.

Comment: Okay, I actually calling this close function from remix by adding amount in weis and bytes in double qoutes. Here i have deployed the contract.
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x0c991fcdcc1cc9ea6398cbc40a71bc2bfae04cbe#code

Comment: I don't see any failed transaction to that contract. It would help if you would actually send the transaction (even though you know it will fail). This way I can see exactly what parameters got passed in.

Comment: Okay Thank you, 
Here's another contract deployed and made a transaction on it.
please have a look.
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xff426de4a1ce0f1a4610eb793c10beb00962a83ad665ea1ea66a0e6a63b0d337

Comment: Could you verify the code for that contract too? Then Etherscan will do some decoding for us.

Comment: Also, can you share the code you used to make that transaction? The code shared here doesn't match the failed transaction (different contract address and different amount). It's hard to debug this without seeing the contract, code, and transaction all together.